# Bug cannot create new catalog

Tags: magento-1.9, category, admin-panel, category-tree, special-character

I am seeing the following broken code with `\n` characters when I go to `Admin->Catalog->Manage Categories`.  I was wondering if someone has a clue what kind of bug is this and how can i fix it.

[image]

Comment: Did you installed any extensions? Error is something related to js as well. Can you check the console for js error?